# Using delete in JavaScript getter / setter to delete the getter / setter

Tags: javascript

This is a question about how JavaScript getters and setters work.

Mozilla's implementation of log4j as a JavaScript module (partial implementation, just the important parts needed for the intended use cases such as in Firefox Sync) contains the following getter/setter definition.

What does the 'delete' in the getter/setter do for you? What does that even mean? It seems to have the effect of making the first use have different results from following uses (but if so, how)?

```
get repository() {
  delete Log4Moz.repository;
  Log4Moz.repository = new LoggerRepository();
  return Log4Moz.repository;
},
set repository(value) {
  delete Log4Moz.repository;
  Log4Moz.repository = value;
},
```

Answer (score 7):

The question (and existing answers) are missing an important piece of context; the getter and setter are defined on the Log4Moz object.  With that in mind, what happens when either the getter or setter is called and it deletes the property for which it is defined?

`delete` on accessor properties (properties with get/set) has the same effect as it does on data properties, namely that it removes the property.  After executing `delete Log4Moz.repository`, the `repository` property is no longer present on the `Log4Moz` object and the getter/setter functions are no longer bound to that property.

The next lines, which assign to `Log4Moz.repository` behave as you would expect.  A data property is created in the `Log4Moz` object with the given value.

In effect, what this does is replace an accessor property with a data property after the first access (either get or set), making a lazily-initialized data property.

Comment: is that a good practice "lazy-initialized data properties"? Haven't seen those around much...

Comment: @DimitryK Good question.  I'd probably recommend against it as being difficult to understand.  Although a [similar idiom is documented on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/get#smart_self-overwriting_lazy_getters), the only code where I've seen it in the wild was Mozilla-related.  Also, I would expect recent JS engines to optimize getter/setter properties well enough that it wouldn't be necessary for performance.  But, as always, your mileage may vary.

Answer (score 1):

FROM MDN:

> The delete operator deletes a property of an object.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/delete

Answer (score 0):

delete operator deletes a property of an object. if you have a object

> o = { a : "hello", b : "world" };

and you do

> delete o.a;

your object will look like this

> o = {b : "world" };

and after that if you do

> o.a = "foo";

it will add new property a to object o and assign it the value "foo" and your object will be like

> o = { a : "foo", b : "world" };

Comment: Would o.a still be a getter (or setter) after that, if it had started out that way? I'd guess not, now it would just be a value, right?  (How can you tell whether a property is a getter/setter or not?  Is there some way to inspect/dump the object that says which properties are getters/setters?)

Answer (score 0):

To answer your specific question, "What does the 'delete' in the getter/setter do for you?" (albeit quite a bit later than when it was asked), given the important information "the getter and setter are defined on the Log4Moz object," the 'delete's prevent an attempt at infinite recursion that will stop when the call stack depth limit is reached. The intent of the code is to lazily assign a property via a getter or settter, but if the 'delete' lines are removed, the getter or setter will be called again from itself instead of assigning a value to a property.